# Access nested Object fields

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I want to access the field names of an object which ist nested into a structure as follows:

```
public class Playerframe
{
  public string Attr1;
  public string Attr2;
}

public class MatchMoment
{
  public int MomentNr;
  public Dictionary <int, Playerframe> PlayerData;
}

public DataTable CreateTable (List<dynamic>Moments)
{
 DataTable table = new DataTable();
 List<string> = Moments[0]...... 

 /// get all class Properties, including the Playerframe properties in order 
 /// to create correctly named DataTable columns
 /// The List<string> should finally contain {"MomentNr","Attr1","Attr2"}

 return table;
}
```

My question now would be how to access the field names("e.g. Attr1") stored in the Dictionary value within a MatchMoment object object using System.Reflection?

I want to write a function which creates a datatable object out of the properties of any given object which is defined in the method parameter, as shown above.

Thx for your help!

Max

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. What have you tried so far? Where do you struggle exactly? Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have and where/what the problem is.

Comment: Why do you specifically want to use reflection? If you provide more context and the desired outcome, perhaps someone can propose a different solution that suits your needs better.

Comment: try this `Dictionary<int, Playerframe> dict = new Dictionary<int, Playerframe>();
Type[] arguments = dict.GetType().GetGenericArguments();
Type key = arguments[0];
PropertyInfo[] value = arguments[1].GetProperties();`

Comment: Hey there, 

thank you for your help!

@Vera

Comment: Hey there, thx for your help!

@Vera I updated my question above, I hope my intend is more clear now. The challenge is to get into this deeply nested Playerframe object (Stored within a Dictionary within a List Object)

Comment: @viveknuna But how would I access this Dictionary Object? As the method parameter takes a dynamic object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following snippet might get you what you want. Basically, it iterates over the properties of the element type of the list to get their names, and in case of a generic property type, recursively gets the names of the properties of the generic type arguments.

```cs
public DataTable CreateTable(List<dynamic> Moments)
{
    var table = new DataTable();

    var elementType = GetElementType(Moments);
    var propertyNames = GetPropertyNames(elementType);

    // Do something with the property names . . .

    return table;
}

private static Type GetElementType(IEnumerable<dynamic> list) =>
    list.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

private static IEnumerable<string> GetPropertyNames(Type t)
{
    return t.GetProperties().SelectMany(getPropertyNamesRecursively);

    IEnumerable<string> getPropertyNamesRecursively(PropertyInfo p) =>
        p.PropertyType.IsGenericType
            ? p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().SelectMany(GetPropertyNames)
            : new[] { p.Name };
}
```

Note that this only looks at properties, and your current classes exclusively use fields. However, the use of properties is considered best practice for public access to data, so it might be worthwhile to change your fields to properties. If you really want to keep them as fields, you might have to tweak it a bit, but the idea of recursively unfolding generic types remains the same.

Comment: Many thanks @Vera, the approach works just fine for me! :)